# Adding pages to PDF/A file with PDFBox without losing PDF/A validity

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm developing a Java application that has to process a folder with PDF/A files, adding a page with some information to each of them using Apache's PDFBox library. The problem is that the output PDF file after adding the information is not PDF/A anymore. This is a validation test from the website: https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx:

[image: Validation output]

And this is the relevant part of the code that I use to generate the PDF file:

```
  String pdfFileName = this.baseFolder+this.extendedPDFFileName;

  File file = new File(pdfFileName); 

  PDDocument pdfFile = PDDocument.load(file);

  PDPage pag = new PDPage();

  // As a test, simply adding a page makes the PDF unvalid as PDF/A
  pdfFile.addPage(pag);

  pdfFile.save(file);

  pdfFile.close();
```

What could I do to keep the PDF/A format validity? Thanks in advance,

Comment: From the error message, it expects resources. So try `pag,setResources(new PDResources());` but I doubt this will be all. You expect PDF/A-1a (accessible) which is more difficult than PDF/A-1b (basic).

Answer (score 1):

As Tilman Hausherr suggested, the problem has been solved by adding a `PDResources` object to the new page, like this:

```
pag.setResources(new PDResources());
```

Now I'm having troubles with the embedded fonts, but this is another question :)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You create a normal PDF in your code, you should create a valid PDF/A from the start.
Here's a link: https://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/cookbook/pdfacreation.html

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment. I've already checked that link, but the information in it is for creating a new PDF/A file from scratch. I do have a valid PDF/A file, so, do you know if it's possible to keep its original format and only add the information I need (basically, few lines of text)?

Comment: Hmm, but why not create a valid PDF/A (my comment above) and just copy your valid PDF/A file to the PDF/A-Object in your code? In your example you use the 'normal' PDF functions, so it seems logic it will output a normal PDF file.

Comment: That link is about creating a PDF/A-1b file. The user wants a PDF/A-1a file.